# Listview problems importing from a csv file

Tags: vb.net, listview, csv

I am creating a listview window that imports data from a CSV file, I created column headers from the CSV file and made sure that it also creates them if they're moved to a different column, let's say like

Subject | Catalog | Section  --------------> Catalog | Subject | Section

```
Try
        fileIn = New StreamReader(strFileIn)
        i = 0
        If Not fileIn.EndOfStream Then
            'CREATES COLUMN HEADERS OUT OF THE CSV FILE, IT WILL ONLY LOOK FOR THESE ITEMS, 
            'CHANGING THE COLUMN HEADERS IN THE CSV FILE WILL NOT AFFECT THE PROGRAM (UNLESS THE NAME IS CHANGED COMPLETELY FROM WHAT IT IS BELOW)
            strLineIn = fileIn.ReadLine
            strFields = strLineIn.Split(","c)
            For i = 0 To strFields.Length - 1
                Select Case strFields(i).ToString
                    Case "Subject"
                        lvwSchedule.Columns.Add(strFields(i))
                    Case "Catalog"
                        lvwSchedule.Columns.Add(strFields(i))
                    Case "Section"
                        lvwSchedule.Columns.Add(strFields(i))
                    Case Else
                        'nothing yet
                End Select
            Next
'Here's what's in the file
'Term   Acad Group  Acad Org    Class Nbr   Subject Catalog Section
'1151   CARTA       ARCHTEC-2   10006       ARC     1132    U01

'Here's where i'm trying to populate
' While Not fileIn.EndOfStream
            strLineIn = fileIn.ReadLine
            strFields = strLineIn.Split(","c)
            Dim lviRow As New ListViewItem(strFields(0))


            For i = 1 To strFields.Length - 1
                    Dim lsiCol As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
                    lsiCol.Text = strFields(i)
                    lviRow.SubItems.Add(lsiCol)
            Next

            'THIS ADDS THE ROW TO THE ListView CONTROL
            lvwSchedule.Items.Add(lviRow)
        End While
End try
```

But when i load the file, it gives me

Subject | Catalog | Section      <----- THIS IS RIGHT

1151         CARTA     ARCTEC-2     <----- THIS IS WRONG

I understand why it's happening, but I've been looking everywhere for the right way to skip a column,

Can someone help me? Also, this is not homework.

Comment: You're splitting on a `,`? I don't see any commas in your code comment showing what's in the file...

Comment: I don't think your code sample even compiles.  I don't see an 'END IF' for 'If Not fileIn.EndOfStream Then'  and I don't see beginning 'While' statement for your 'END WHILE'.  For your question, you're only using the last three columns from your CSV, so why don't you just start at strFields(4) when populating your listview?

Comment: @JeffBridgman yea, i'm splitting at a comma, and for example let's say its
1151, CARTA,  ARCHTEC-2, 10006, ARC.... etc

Comment: @Shar1er80  i didn't post all the code thinking it was obvious that I closed all my loops and if statements, and starting at strFields(4) wouldn't work, because there's a lot more columns that I actually need to put in and there's times where i need 3 columns right after the other, skip 2, grab another 1, and like that. I want to program it so that in the future it just grabs certain columns instead of every column in the CSV file

Comment: You're using a StreamReader and you don't want to get every column? Sounds like you need to load your data into a Dataset or a List<> of a custom object that represents your csv lines. Then query that data for whatever columns/data that you want.